# Why did Dredd nuke Mega-City 2?

Tags: dredd

So, I was peacefully <strike>indulging my crippling addiction</strike> er... <strike>uselessly wasting time</strike> err... doing important research on TVTropes, when I ran into [this mention in one example](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AirstripOne):

> but Dredd nuked Mega-City 2

That seems both slightly overly drastic and not really in line with my - admittedly limited - understanding of the character of Judge Dredd, who's all about punishing the guilty, not indiscriminate slaughter or random acts of mass murder.

So, why did Dredd choose to nuke Mega-City 2?

Comment: He also destroyed East-Meg One (with a loss of approx 500M non-combatants) at the end of the Apocalypse War; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Apocalypse_War

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destruction of Mega-City Two occurs at the height of the [Judgement Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgement_Day_(Judge_Dredd)) story arc. Sabbat the Necromagus has begun raising the dead and Judges from around the world have convened in Hondo-Cit to discuss their options for preventing the planet from being overrun.

Dredd suggests that they nuke Mega-City Two (as well as Djakarta, Brasilia, Sino-Cit and South-Am) to prevent them from providing a source of zombies for Sabbat's armies.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

NOTE : I've edited the frames above for ease of reading

Comment: This is also a textbook example of why you need to attend staff meetings, even if you think you're too busy elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

In 2114, it was overrun with zombies created by the necromagus Sabbat in the storyline *[Judgement Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgement_Day_(Judge_Dredd_story))*. So to prevent Sabbat having a zombie army, it was nuked.